# How do I aknowledge that all events get captured in azure?

Tags: python, azure, azure-eventhub

While using Azure's event hub, how can we know that all events sends/receive ?.Is there Any option/solution to track this? Because both are working asynchronously.

Answer (score -1):

Check the **Capture** option "on" when creating event hub:
[image]

Then you could check the messages in storage account:
[image]

By the way, I use the code in this tutorial to send messages to event hub: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-python-get-started-send

Comment: If this post helps, then please consider Accept it as the answer to help the other members find it more quickly.